# different responses from http.get when using params vs hardcoded URL

Tags: angularjs, parameters, get

I've got a function to pull government representatives using the [Google Civic Information API](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/), which works as expected when I submit a hardcoded URL, but only returns a small subset when I try to pass the same query using PARAMS. Both test functions are getting a 200 response.

function with query parameters hardcoded in the URL:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=my-google-api-key&address=114%20Grand%20St%20Albany%20NY%2012202&fields=officials'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
      console.log("it didn't work.");
    });      

};
```

console logs a response with 26 officials.

function with query parameters passed via PARAMS:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives',
    params: {
      key: 'my-google-api-key',
      address: '114%20Grand%20St%20Albany%20NY%2012202',
      fields: 'officials'
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
      console.log("it didn't work.");
    });      

};
```

console logs only 8 of the officials.

I've been up and down the AngularJS API refs for $http, $http.get, and $httpParamSerializer, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I could be missing.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `114 Grand St Albany NY 12202` as the address parameter instead of `114%20Grand%20St%20Albany%20NY%2012202`.

It should look like:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives',
    params: {
      key: 'my-google-api-key',
      address: '114 Grand St Albany NY 12202',
      fields: 'officials'
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
   console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log("it didn't work.");
  });      

};
```

I think that by passing `114%2520Grand%2520St%2520Albany%2520NY%252012202` as param it will get URL encoded twice and you will lose information.